# Changing input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, key, key-bindings

The main problem is, that I want to write Georgian characters in input even with Latin keyboard. My code works like this: on keydown, it gets the char of the key pressed, then finds it's Georgian equivalent, and adds the char to the value in the field. The code works fine but, when it comes to the edge of the input, the string is not moving and I can't see the updated value. I tried to focus on input on keyup but that doesn't help(as it's already focused); Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Thanks in advance for help.

```
  var aaa = {};
  aaa["a"] = "0x10d0";


  aaa["b"] = "0x10d1";
  aaa["g"] = "0x10d2";
  aaa["d"] = "0x10d3";
  aaa["e"] = "0x10d4";
  aaa["v"] = "0x10d5";
  aaa["z"] = "0x10d6";

  aaa["T"] = "0x10d7"; // t
  aaa["i"] = "0x10d8";
  aaa["k"] = "0x10d9";
  aaa["l"] = "0x10da";
  aaa["m"] = "0x10db";
  aaa["n"] = "0x10dc";
  aaa["o"] = "0x10dd";
  aaa["p"] = "0x10de";
  aaa["J"] = "0x10df"; // zh
  aaa["r"] = "0x10e0";
  aaa["s"] = "0x10e1";
  aaa["t"] = "0x10e2"; // t

  aaa["u"] = "0x10e3";
  aaa["f"] = "0x10e4"; 
  aaa["q"] = "0x10e5";
  aaa["R"] = "0x10e6"; // gh/g
  aaa["y"] = "0x10e7";
  aaa["S"] = "0x10e8"; // sh
  aaa["C"] = "0x10e9"; // ch
  aaa["c"] = "0x10ea"; // ts
  aaa["Z"] = "0x10eb"; // dz
  aaa["w"] = "0x10ec"; // ts
  aaa["W"] = "0x10ed"; // ch/tch
  aaa["x"] = "0x10ee"; // kh
  aaa["j"] = "0x10ef";
  aaa["h"] = "0x10f0";

  var aab = {};
  for (var key in aaa) {
    aab[aaa[key]]=key;
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var tbox_lemma = document.getElementById("tbox_lemma");
    tbox_lemma.onkeypress = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var keycode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
      var c = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
      if( c in aaa ) {
        var txtToAdd = String.fromCharCode(aaa[String.fromCharCode(keycode)]);
        var caretPos1 = tbox_lemma.selectionStart;
        var caretPos2 = tbox_lemma.selectionEnd;
        var val = tbox_lemma.value;
        tbox_lemma.value = val.substring(0, caretPos1) + txtToAdd + val.substring(caretPos2);
        tbox_lemma.selectionStart = caretPos1 + 1;
        tbox_lemma.selectionEnd = tbox_lemma.selectionStart;
        return false;
      }
    };
  };
```

Here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/4dczfknx/

The problem is on Chrome. On firefox it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, add this line to the end of your onload function:

```
$('#tbox_lemma').blur().focus().val($('#tbox_lemma').val());
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5cotkrct/)</kbd>

Comment: The problem now is that it does not work in Firefox :(

Comment: neither on internet explorer

Comment: **Works** for me on **Chrome** Version 39.0.2171.99 m | **Works** on **Firefox** Version 34.0.5 | **Works** on **Internet Explorer** Version 10.0.9200.17028 - Windows 8 Enterprise

Comment: I don't know, on my mac it does not work. Searching for possible solutions, I found that firefox may use a policy, that after one blur() or focus() they don't execute any more such functions, to avoid some loops. So I tried now creating an input with opacity 0, and then :

hiddenInput.focus();
   setTimeout(function(){
    searchInput.focus();
   },1);
Works fine on all browsers, anyway, thanks for help